# Regular expression remove the letters on the sides

Tags: regex

I can't find an expression which can remove all letters on both sides of a line.

Data sample:

```
Valencia 7x16/5x114.3 D71.6 ET48 Dark
```

I need to remove all letters on sides such as `Valencia` and `Dark`, so the output from previous string should be:

```
7x16/5x114.3 D71.6 ET48
```

I tried using the following expression but it didn't work:

```
[^x./ETD\s0-9]
```

Comment: "it didn't work"? Did you get the wrong result (which)? Did you get an error message? Did nothing happen? How did you use the expression? Which language/environment are you using it in?

Answer (score 1):

You don't technically need a regex for this:

```
$output = trim($input,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ");
```

But it'd probably be easier.

```
$output = preg_replace("/^\S+\s|\s\S+$/","",$input);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression will:

- remove all letters at the beginnning or end of a string upto the first space character

Regex: `^[a-z]*\s|\s[a-z]*$`

Replace with: empty string

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com?3607j)

**Sample Text**

```
Valencia 7x16/5x114.3 D71.6 ET48 Dark
```

**After Replacement**

```
7x16/5x114.3 D71.6 ET48
```